# Would like to convert from a PHP row to a column

Tags: php, html

I have a ranking system on my website and I would like it to display in a column rather than a row.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, ROUND(score/(1+(losses/wins))) AS performance FROM images ORDER BY ROUND(score/(1+(losses/wins))) DESC LIMIT 0,10");

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) $top_ratings[] = (object) $row;
```

Comment: iterate through the results and prepare the structure you want

Comment: It's html. There's a million way to do it. From <br> to using a table.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Where is your html output?